# How can I monitor my Samba traffic?

Tags: samba, monitoring, shared-folders

I've got a directory shared on my network, using Samba. People on the netwerk use this Samba share to download files from my share to their computers. I'm interested in what files are downloaded most, and by which users they are downloaded. I'd like to see this in real time, if possible. Is there a program that allows me to do this? If yes, how can I use it?

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get Samba to log stuff like that. Check the Samba `man` pages, via `man -k samba`. Read `man smb.conf` and see the sections **Log File** and **Log Level**

Comment: Could you explain in some more detail what I should do exactly? Is it enough to just add `log file = ~/samba-log.%m` to `/etc/samba/smb.conf`?

Comment: No! The file path you give `~/samba-log.%m` uses the "`~`" shortcut for "my home directory", a meaningless concept to the Samba daemon.  

Warning: I'm not running Samba on this computer, so I can't test any of this, so YMMV.  

Have you read the `man smb.conf`? When I did, it suggested that `log file = /var/log/samba/snoop-log.%m` and `log level = 10` would be a good start.

Comment: I did read it, but I found it hard to interpret. You're right about the first poit, though. I want the logs to land in my home directory if possible, so I changed the path to `/home/MyName/samba-log.%m`. I'll try the line you adviced right now though.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I've added the following stuff to `etc/samba/smb.conf`, right under the share:
 `loglevel = 10`
 `# log per machine`
 `logfile = /var/log/samba/samba-machinelog.%m`
 `#log per user`
 `logfile = /var/log/samba/samba-userlog.%u`

Do you see anything that could be wrong here?

Comment: Did you restart samba? Did you run Samba's `testparm` (after reading the man page)?  

Yes there is something wrong with what you added to `smb.conf`! You misspelled several words. "loglevel" should be "log level", "logfile" should be "log file", as shown in `man smb.conf`.

Comment: I changed the words, but it still doesn't save text files at `/var/log/samba`. Do you see anything that could be causing the problem?

Comment: Did you restart samba? Did you run Samba's `testparm` (after reading the man page)?

Comment: Yup, I did those things. I read the man page until the parameter part, with the exception of `log file`, and `log level`. It still doesn't make the text files, very strange.

Comment: I'm stumped. Try following the links given by Google: http://www.google.com/search?q=samba+log

Comment: It turned out that I had the parameters `log level` and `log file` written right under the share section `[MyShare]`, while I should have written it under the section `[global]`, in subsection `#### Debugging/Accounting ####`. This discussion helped me a lot though, so thanks for that. I'll mark this answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 10):

just try next :

```
sudo watch smbstatus
```

This will continually redisplay a CLI status of SMB connections, like 'top'.

Comment: SMB connections may linger for weeks after the last file transfer (if any).

Answer (score 0):

`vfs_audit` or `vfs_full_audit` may be best in this case.  The latter allows you to select which events you want to monitor.  See https://serverfault.com/a/736783/127791 for how to configure `vfs_full_audit`.  In this case I think the `open` event is the one you'd want (or `openat` - I found that `open` wasn't recognized, and then *all* events were logged).